# Appointment Slot Check Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I made a Web App in Eclipse with Java. The user can make appointments. The doctors can set their availability. If there is available doctor the user can make an appointment. However, I want to display the available time slots (for the user to make an appointment) but this time slot has to be free from any scheduled appointment. Please note that every appointment lasts one hour.

The data are stored in a MySQL database. The tables are structured like this:

Doctors:

- ID
- Name
- Surname
- Email
- Password
- Specialty

Appointment:

- ID
- DoctorID
- UserID
- Date
- Report

Availability:

- ID
- DoctorID
- STime
- ETime

With the following queries I get the required data.

```
Select  a.DoctorID, a.Date from appointment a

Select d.ID, d.Specialty, a.STime, a.ETime from  doctors d INNER JOIN availability a ON a.DoctorID=d.ID where d.Specialty=?
```

How can I display the available time slots checking there is no appointment at the available time slots?

Comment: Seems like `Appointment` would also need `startTime` and `endTime`, and `Availability` would also need a date.  Then given a particular date, in the JSP (or equivalent) iterate over `Availability`.  For each available slot see if there is already a corresponding `Appointment`.

Comment: Every appointment last one hour! Sorry forgot to say that!

Comment: I agree with Andrew S in making that modification to your database. You need to add some sort of delimiter to will be used to distinguish whether or not the doctor has a booked appointment. That Availability table is almost useless. I'd add startTime endTime to Doctor (using these as when he's on staff 9am-5pm) and then using Appointment with startTime endTime. When a user selects an hour-block for an Appointment then fill in the start/end, and then when querying if the Doctor is available check over his start/end against the start/end of all the Appointments

Comment: So the best way is to alter the table Appointment? 
I need the table availability cause the doctor has to put his free time. If he has free time then an appointment could be made.